# PHP - Individual array items as parameters for method

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, methods, parameters

Is it possible to easily pass the individual items of an array to a method as parameters?

Like so:

Edit2:

I changed my code to show 'a solution', the problem with this solution is that it is deprecated since PHP 4.1 and removed in PHP 7.

```
<?php
    $builder = new Builder;
    $params = array('This is number: ', 4);

    echo call_user_method_array('add', $builder, $params);

    class Builder {
        public function add($string1, $number1) {
            return $string1 . $number1;
        }
    }
?>
```

Edit:

I made a mistake by using a simple example. The reason I am wondering whether this is possible is not for a function that returns a string like that. It is to create a MVC-like framework. The solution has to be all-round.

Comment: pass array and `implod` it, or save array element in some variable and the pass it to function

Comment: Try like this : `public function add($params) {
            return implode('',$params);
        }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to stick with your general solution, just use the proper *non-deprecated* method:

```
echo call_user_func_array([$builder, 'add'], $params);
```

Reference: [`callable`](https://secure.php.net/manual/language.types.callable.php)

Demo: https://3v4l.org/4VFi6

Answer (score 2):

Use `implode()` method.

```
<?php
    $builder = new Builder;
    $params = array('This is number: ', 4);

    echo $builder->add($params); //returns 'This is number: 4'

    class Builder {
        public function add($params) {
            return implode('', $params);
        }
    }
?>
```

**Output**

```
This is number: 4
```

**Check Online Demo : [Click Here](https://eval.in/559715)**

**OR**

Pass 2 parameters `$params[0],$params[1]`.

```
<?php
    $builder = new Builder;
    $params = array('This is number: ', 4);

    echo $builder->add($params[0],$params[1]); //returns 'This is number: 4'

    class Builder {
        public function add($string1 ,$number1) {

            return $string1 . $number1;
        }
    }
?>
```

**Online Demo : [Click Here](https://eval.in/559725)**

Comment: it should be `return implode('',$params);` since OP adds space in the array value itself

Comment: I edited my post, my example code is not the only use-case I have for this problem. And as such the solution needs to be all-round.

Comment: not clear. what you want exactly. Do you want to pass 2 parameters in function? what is your main issue?

Comment: Still facing issue? Please describe your issue in detail. @kgongonowdoe

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more generic approach:

Just pass the array to the function and *iterate* through it by using a `foreach-loop`

```
<?php
    $builder = new Builder;
    $params = array('This is number: ', 4);

    $builder->add($params); //returns 'This is number: 4'

    class Builder {
        public function add($array) {
            foreach($array as $key => $value){
                //Do something with your values here if you want
                return $key . $value;
            }
        }
    }
?>
```